# JAX-B marshalling issue

Tags: java

I have to do marshaling using JAX-B. I have `Customer` class, `Person` class
`Customer` is having `List<Person> personList` as an attribute. I have taken

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer  {

private List<Person> personList;

@XmlElement
public List<Person> getPersonList() {
    return personList;
}
```

I am getting the O/P `<customer><personList>person details</personList>` but I want person details inside `</person></dependents></customer>`

Comment: I want person details like this <customer><personList><person>person details</person><personList></customer> instead of <customer><personList>person details</personList></customer>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@XmlElementWrapper` like this one

*Customer.java*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "customer")
public class Customer  {

    private List<Person> personList;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "personList")
    @XmlElement(name="person")
    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }
}
```

*Person.java*

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "person")
public class Person {

    private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

After that your output should look like the following xml

```
<customer>
    <personList>
        <person>
            <name>Person 1</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Person 2</name>
        </person>
    <personList>
</customer>
```

Comment: @Suma1810 Please accept this answer if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how your final XML should look, but this website has a great example for JAX-B which is excellent for reference (both marshalling and unmarshalling):

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/30/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/

You probably forgot to annotate the `Person` class.

Comment: I have annotated Person class attributes like firstname ,lastname with @XmlElement ...Customer also contains Person individually as an attribute along with PersonList(List<Person>)...Do I need to annotate anything more in Person class???I think only one XmlRootElement annotation  which is in Customer class..

Comment: @XmlElementWrapper(name = "personList")
    @XmlElement(name="person")
worked...Thanks a lot..Thank you ...